# Is there anything behind this door?

Tags: hiversaires

I just finished **Hiversaires**, which is an awesome game. I suspect, however, that I haven't discovered all of the game's secrets. (I made it to the credits, but in these kind of games, you never can be sure that you're really done.) Specifically, I'm wondering if anyone has figured out whether or not there's anything behind this door:

[image: A picture of the door with a spotlight on it, some runes on it, and symbol and other runes above.]

You don't have to tell me *what* is back there; just let me know *if* you've been able to go through it.

In case it helps,

> from [the developer's website](http://wiki.xxiivv.com/Needle%20numbers), the engravings on the door are called "needle numbers" or "Percean runes."

Comment: How do you get to that door?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there's something behind that door.

If you want a hint:

> These runes can be translated into a date.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. It's best practice to leave a much more explicit answer. If you're worried about spoiling the challenge, just use spoiler tags :)

Comment: Is it better to just blatantly ruin the puzzle instead of hint at the solution? (The person posting the above comment is the author of the game.)

Comment: @underscorediscovery hence Alice Rees' suggestion of using spoiler tags... If one still has to keep guessing after reading an answer, then it's not considered a complete answer.

Comment: I gave it an edit, assuming that the dev giving a hint means that, yes, there's something behind it. Ideally I think there should be a second spoiler that says *what* so that people can choose if they just want the hint or if they just want the whole secret revealed, but that's not really necessary.

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks!

Comment: And by the way, if you're the real [Devine Linvega](http://twitter.com/aliceffekt), let me just say that the game rocks. I love all games in the Myst style, and this one nails it! The music was great, the art was fantastic, the puzzles were well-designed; it's an all-around awesome game!

Comment: Thank you, glad you like it. I gave a hint. If you can figure out the date it opens, you will see what is behind. Best of luck !